# Where did the internal space go on my HTC Desire?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire, internal-storage

I know this a common problem, but my experience has been a little freakish.  I am using an HTC Desire 2.2 and usually try to maintain approximately 40 MB space free.  I have installed the bloody gigantic Google+ which took up about 20 MB and there was an option to move it the SD card, which I did.  Apparently only some of the 20 MB was moved, I think about 12 MB. Okay no problem, I thought, used Google+ for some time, not my thing, so I uninstalled it and couldn't believe that I'm still short the 8MB of space!

My question is where did it go? And can I get it back?  8mb is precious on the Desire.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with moving applications to the sdcard is usually not the application, the problem is their data. The google+ app is like 8mb or so, but if you look in the application manager it will show a lot more then that. Mine is ~40mb. This is because the amount of data that the application stores.

Android needs to address the /datadata and /data locations and allocate more in them or allow users to move this information to other storage locations. I have had to, on multiple occasions, go in to the application manager and clear the data for apps like google+, and I have a Galaxy S device. Granted, I do have over 70 applications installed total, but only a small percentage of them actually use up 95% of the storage.

A lot of people bring up, usually with tablets, the ability to support multiple users, this is one of the reasons this will not happen in the foreseeable future. If the devices can support the data storage needed for one user, how can they support multiple users.